# iOS - Running app error, unknown error code

Tags: ios, ipad

When I try to run my app on simulator, it is crash and show error code like below.

> Couldn't register com.andikurnia.integraASP.FlipView with the
>   bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code. This generally means that
>   another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the
>   debugger.

Is there anyone can help me with this error. I clean up my code on xcode and build it again, but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: I think reboot your mac will do work. :)

Comment: thank you for your response. It run again... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember that I had similar problem. To fix this you can into nasty way.

```
Just restart your mac.
```

Comment: wew, it run again. thank you so much....

btw, How could it be..? would you explain to me about this problem..?

Comment: I have problems with different devices. Xcode says "Broken pipe" - for this error you must get out cable from device and connect it again. Probably, you have run project while simulator are not responding and debugger hangs up.